# WinRT as a replacement of Win32 API

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

Over internet there are many blogs saying that winrt is a replacement of win32 api. IS this is really true? Even i read that application developed for Metro Application uses winrt. So do i understand correctly, those application which are metro application they has to go through winrt & classic applications has to go through win32 api's. Please someone validate my conclusions.

Answer (score 10):

Disclaimer: I am not involved in any way in the design or implementation of Windows 8, and I have only kept up on the Windows 8 news.  I possess **no** privileged information.

> winrt is a replacement of win32 api

Microsoft has made clear that WinRT is not a replacement for Win32, but another way to develop applications.  That said, there is no Win32 implementation on ARM (at least that third-party developers can access).  Windows on ARM will only support WinRT, and not Win32, as Steve Sinofsky explains [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/02/09/building-windows-for-the-arm-processor-architecture.aspx).

> those application which are metro application they has to go through winrt & classic applications has to go through win32 api's

Absolutely correct.

Comment: Note that Metro does support a rather limited subset of Win32 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205757.aspx), on both x86 and ARM.

Comment: Always add a "Not yet", because this is a simple marketing decision to gain and protect market shares.

Comment: Some WinRT APIs can only be called by Windows store applications while others can only be called by desktop applications. Still others can be called by either one. The documentation indicates which are supported in the requirements section.

Answer (score 5):

Win32 still exists. WinRt wraps them and converts their types to be native for the consuming language. C++ metro application can still access a limited set of Win32 APIs

Answer (score 3):

WinRT is basically a wrapper for Win32 (COM) to be consumed by Metro Stype applications (Projections for Native, CLR, Javascript) which are designed for a sandboxed environment mostly for Touch-Screen aware applications (although one can hack them to work on the desktop). Some APIs for Metro Style applications are still using the classic COM APIs (DirectX for example). 
So, how can WinRT replace Win32 if it is built upon it? ;-)

Comment: If you think of winrt as being COM related, you're ignoring most of the power of winrt.  Yes, deep down in the bowels of winrt, COM constructs are used.  But developers should never see that.  Instead they use the language projections which provide a natural and familiar API surface - the APIs feel like the APIs that developers using that language are used to.

Comment: @LarryOsterman OMG Larry Osterman responded to my post *faints*