# VB6 on Windows 8 ARM based Tablets

Tags: vb6, arm, windows-8, tablet

With the announcement that VB6 will be supported on Windows 8, my question is:

Is there any place where Microsoft has said (Yes or No) VB6 apps will run on the ARM based Tablets?

And, if not, is there any ARM emulator, so we could test our VB6 apps on a Windows 8 ARM Tablet?

Comment: I would imagine [read: hope] that Windows 8 is Windows 8 ... (Microsoft lives on backwards compatibility, does't it? ;-)

Comment: But, VB6 compiles (via an altered version of the C++ 4.1 compiler, if I remember correctly) machine code for the intel/AMD architecture so ... I'm not sure how intel/AMD machine code could run on an ARM chip.

Comment: VB 6.0 uses a specialized version of the same second-pass compiler VC 6.0 uses. This generates x86 code for input to Link.exe, which produces x86 PE file output. Without an x86 emulator like the one Windows uses on ia64 (Itanium) there is no way for VB6 programs to run on ARM machines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My understanding is: No.  Windows 8 will support 2 different APIs: Win32 (and .NET on top of that) and WinRT.  The Windows 8 ARM builds will only support WinRT.  VB6 is compiled against the Win32 API, it won't work on the ARM tablets.

As explained by Adam Mihalcin [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9356950/17635).

Answer (score 1):

On ARM, there are no 3rd party desktop apps, VB6 or otherwise.  And you won't see support for VB6 with the new Metro framework because... well... VB6 was deprecated like 10 years ago.

It's time to invest in a rewrite.

Comment: I think you're wrong.  Windows 8 does support VB6 - that's a promise from MS.  The metro framework != windows 8.  In fact, there is no "metro framework", I think you mean "WinRT".  They're not dropping support for VB6, they just won't have support for Win32 on ARM, but they'll still work fine on Intel/AMD devices, which is all that Windows 7 or earlier runs on now anyways.  You can't just say "It's time to invest in a rewrite" without doing a cost-benefit analysis on that.  It's quite likely you'll be able to run VB6 and other Win32 apps for many years.

Comment: @ScottWhitlock: Robert said that "ARM doesn't support VB6", not "Windows 8 doesn't support VB6"